# Possible apache / php exploits

Tags: php, apache, security

I have a question about exploiting a php server.

If I restrict all write access to the file system which the web server is running on. What kind of possible exploits can be run to gain access to the server?

And of course the server is running as a standard user.

Can this be regarded as a secure server then?

Comment: Yep, http://serverfault.com might help, as might http://security.stackexchange.com/. Both of them are sister sites to SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an exploit exists that can give the hacker root access, then no amount of permission settings will stop him writing to the file system.

I don't know of any root exploits in PHP or Apache at the moment, but that's not to say they don't exist.

In addition, if the PHP program calls any external programs (via `exec()`, `system()`, etc), then those programs also pose the same theoretical risk. And if the PHP program uses `eval()` in an insecure way, then the attacker could theoretically call *any* program on the system, again with the same level of risk.

However, his kind of attack is relatively rare; most hacks against PHP software tend to be database attacks, because that's often the weak point in the program code, and also often offers better rewards to the attacker than a file system hack.

Of course, if the entire file system is write protected, then the DB won't be able to make updates either, which would prevent some kinds of DB attack (but would also likely be a problem for your normal DB usage). But a database attack could be in many forms, from simply reading the user passwords to inserting malicious data into the DB, and not all of them require write access. So write protection only goes so far to help you here.

Depending on what you mean by "restrict all write access", you may also have problems with software that expects to be able to write to the file system, including Apache, which writes a log file of activity. Not being able to write to this may be okay for Apache, but it will seriously impare your ability to work out what happened when an attack does occur.